How do I deploy Isolated Azure Function App to Azure with multiple artifact files?
I have upgraded my function app to .NET 8 using the isolated worker model and am trying to deploy new builds to Azure. With the change to the isolated worker model, my build artifacts now contain two zip files, MyFunctionApp.zip. and WorkerExtensions.zip. This causes the Azure Function App Deploy release pipeline task to fail with the following error "Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip. Please restrain the search pattern."
My build uses a simple publish step in the build pipeline:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    projects: MyApp.Functions/**/*.csproj
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    publishWebProjects: False
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
    artifactName: "fa-artifacts-build"
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

Which results in both the MyApp.Functions.zip and WorkerExtensions.zip files. My release pipeline then uses
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy'
  inputs:
    connectedServiceNameARM: 'Azure - 1234'
    appType: functionApp
    appName: 'my-function-app'
    deploymentMethod: zipDeploy

Looking over the documentation for AzureFunctionApp@2 I do not see any configurations to. allow both zips to be deployed at once, as my understanding is that with the isolated worker model the WorkerExtensions.zip is needed.

Did you try to use the auto generated .yaml file? I am able to deploy an isolated function to the function app using auto generated .yaml file

@IkhtesamAfrin Auto generated from where? Using the isolated function template when creating a new project there was nothing generated

Once you push the changes you can create the build by selecting the given template which generate the .yaml file

Instead of ZIP the artifacts when running the "dotnet publish" step, you can use the ArchiveFiles@2 task to archive the output artifacts as a ZIP file after the "dotnet publish" step.
See below sample as reference.
jobs:
- job: build
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet build'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: 'MyApp.Functions/**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
      publishWebProjects: false
      zipAfterPublish: false
      modifyOutputPath: false
  
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: 'Archive Files'
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build_$(Build.BuildId).zip'
  
  - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
    displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy'
    inputs:
      connectedServiceNameARM: 'ARM-Service-Connection-Name'
      appType: 'functionApp'
      appName: 'App-Name'
      package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'

You also can reference the documentation "Build and deploy using Azure Pipelines".


When I do this, the artifact is a single zip that contains 2 directories, MyApp.Functions and WorkerExtensions. When I release that and go to Azure, my function app gets wiped out inside the resource and it looks like its empty now. The only way I've gotten this to work is changing the Publish step to specifically target MyApp.Functions.csproj so that I never have the WorkerExtensions.csproj in the zip. But I thought WorkerExtensions would be needed

@Matt, If 'MyApp.Functions.csproj' depends on 'WorkerExtensions.csproj', when building 'MyApp.Functions.csproj', as far as I know, it normally will also build 'WorkerExtensions.csproj' and add the generated DLL files to the built output directory 'MyApp.Functions.csproj' for use.

The **/*.csproj tries to search for all .csproj projects including the auto-generated WorkerExtensions.csproj project. Then, you'll end up with multiple zip files.
Try projects: 'MyApp.Functions/**/MyApp.Functions.csproj' The WokerExtensions will then be part of the build and included in the final zip file.
Cheers,
Martin
